# Domain repeated twice in 404 error page when using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am developing a .htaccess file for my site to clean up the urls. I am trying to rename my contact page to make sure its working but I keep getting a 404 error page saying that my url missing. The .htaccess files appears to be working fine but my domain is being repeated in the 404 error page. Here is my .htaccess file so far.

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite for contact.php
RewriteRule ^message$ contact.php [NC,L]
```

Here is the 404 error

> The requested URL `/domain.com/domain.com/contact.php` was not found
>   on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

My .htaccess file is in the root of my site. It is probably a simple problem but I have been trying all the solutions I could find but to no avail.

Comment: Use `/contact.php` there

Comment: Thank hjpotter92, that worked. It was driving me crazy thinking it was a much larger problem. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is, you are using relative links when rewriting URL. This causes the server to look for `/domain.com/domain.com/contact.php`.

Use absolute URL in rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^message$ /contact.php [NC,L]
```